# Show alert and play sound when countdown timers are done

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Trying to get an alert and play a sound when different timers are done. JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Walter69/pc8q0sft/10/

HTML:

```
<section id="time">
<section id="timer1" state="">
<span>0:00</span>
<div onClick="time[this.innerHTML]('timer1')">start</div>
<div onClick="time.cancel('timer1')">cancel</div>
</section>
<section id="timer2" state="">
<span>0:00</span>
<div onClick="time[this.innerHTML]('timer2')">start</div>
<div onClick="time.cancel('timer2')">cancel</div>
</section>
<section id="timer3" state="">
<span>0:00</span>
<div onClick="time[this.innerHTML]('timer3')">start</div>
<div onClick="time.cancel('timer3')">cancel</div>
</section>
</section>
<audio class="sound1" src="audio/timer.mp3"></audio>
```

JS:

```
let d = document,
    id = 'getElementById',
    time = {
//Multiple Timers
//[current time, time setting, (pause/running), HTML section#timer]
      timer1: ['0:05', '0:05', 0, d[id]('timer1')],
      timer2: ['2:30', '2:30', 0, d[id]('timer2')],
      timer3: ['5:00', '5:00', 0, d[id]('timer3')],

//Manage Timer Functions
      reset: function(t) {time[t][0] = time[t][1];},
      pause: function(t) {time[t][2] = 0;time.state(t,'pause');time.button(t,'resume');},
      resume: function(t) {time[t][2] = 1;time.state(t,'running');time.button(t,'pause');},
      set: function(t,s) {time[t][0] = s; time[t][1] = s;},
      state: function(t,s) {time[t][3].setAttribute('state',s);},
      button: function(t,s) {time[t][3].querySelector('div').innerHTML = s;},
      cancel: function(t) {time[t][2] = 0;time.reset(t);time.state(t,'');time.button(t,'start');time.setTimer(t);},
      start: function(t) {time.reset(t);time[t][2] = 1;time.state(t,'running');time.button(t,'pause');},
      getTimers: function() {return Object.keys(time).filter(function (n) {return n.indexOf("ti")==0;});},
      setTimer: function(t) {time[t][3].querySelector('span').innerHTML = time[t][0]},
      setTimers: function(x) {
        let times = time.getTimers();
        for (var i=0,t;i<times.length;i++) {t=times[i];
              if(time[t][2]||x){time[t][3].querySelector('span').innerHTML = time[t][0]}
        }
  },
};

//handle seconds passed
function convertSeconds(s=0) {return new Date(s*1000).toISOString().substr(11,8).replace(/^(00:0(?=[1-9])|00:|0)/gm, '')}
function toSeconds(t) {t=t.split(':').reverse();return (t[2]*3600||0)+(t[1]*60||0)+t[0]*1||0;}

//set HTML times onLoad
time.setTimers(1)

function runTimer(times){times = time.getTimers();time.setTimers();
    function run(t,s,l){if(t&&t[2]){s=toSeconds(t[0]);t[0]=s?convertSeconds(s-1):'00:00'&&(time.cancel(l));}}
    for (var i=0,t;i<times.length;i++) {run(time[times[i]],'',times[i])}
}

//run timer every second reguardless of whether timer is paused or running
setInterval(runTimer, 1000)
```

For the alert and sound I'm thinking something like this but I don't know how to implement it and run it independently on each timer (and if it's even remotely correct):

```
if (timer < 0) {
alert("Time's up!");
$('.sound1').get(0).play();
}
```